# Make windows server 2008 R2 iso image a bootable dvd

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have windows server 2008 iso file of size almost 3GB. How could I make a bootable 2008 server DVD?. I thought I could install on the machine on which an os has already been installed, just by copying and executing the iso image but I heard it's not possible. Any free tool to make a bootable 2008 server dvd?.

Comment: The 4 answers are excellent!. What I was about to do on windows server 2008 R2 are in the series of below answers. I can't mark one as accepted solution but all the four. If anything could be done equally to all the answers, please let me know anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ISO record](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm)er which should work on a windows box.

Comment: Thanks!. I would use this to make bootable 2008 server dvd.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to make it work just by making a bootable image of an existing installation (which is what I understand you are saying). You might be able to make a bootable ISO, using some LiveCD creation type of environment, that includes the Windows Server 2008 ISO image and tools for copying the ISO directly to a physical drive. You will also need to do quite a bit of additional work, creating a Windows 2008 boot environment and modifying it to actually boot on the phsyical instance you create. And you might\will have to do some preparatory work to ensure the image contains drivers for all the hardware you might be considering installing this on.

It's certainly possible in principle - P2P and V2P migration tools do something very similar - but it's not a trivial exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com) and then follow instructions [how to burn iso image with ImgBurn](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/G/Burning+ISO+Images+with+ImgBurn). If it's iso you've downloaded from Microsoft it should already be bootable so just burning it the way described in `how to` should be enough. Then simply start your computer from that DVD and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to deploy Windows Server 2008 via disk, then you will need the original installation media, or a copy of it.  You can then boot from this to do a standard install.  As this seems like a pretty obvious answer, I assume you want to further customise your installs.  To do that you'll need a tool like System Center Configuration Manager (not free) or Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (free I believe) or Windows Automated Installation Kit (free).

Read more on officially sanctioned options at these links:

- [Windows Server 2008 Deployment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee344846(WS.10).aspx)
- [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx)
- [Windows Automated Installation Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349343(WS.10).aspx)